# LinQ font size display problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

OK, so I'm using LINQ to generate a tag cloud based on tags in my database. I have a problem that I really can't seem to figure out. The first time I add a tag, it displays in the biggest font (36pt) - I guess because of the % value calculated, weight takes on the value of 100 and is passed to GetTagSize(). Is there a way to place an if statement where I'm doing this: weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100
to check for count of 1 and display the smallest font? Thanks for your help!

```
var tagSummaryNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                         join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                         join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                         join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                         join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                         join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                         where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                               pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                               it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                               pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                               s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                               psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                         group af by af.Name into tagGroup

                         select new
                         {

                             Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                             tagCount = tagGroup.Count()

                         };

int maxTagFrequencyNegative = (from t in tagSummaryNegative select (int?)t.tagCount).Max() ?? 0;


var tagCloudNegative = from af in db.AgileFactors
                   join psf in db.ProjectStoryFactors on af.AgileFactorID equals psf.AgileFactorID
                   join s in db.Stories on psf.StoryID equals s.StoryID
                   join pim in db.ProjectIterationMembers on s.ProjectIterationMemberID equals pim.ProjectIterationMemberID
                   join it in db.Iterations on pim.ProjectIterationID equals it.ProjectIterationID
                   join pro in db.Projects on it.ProjectID equals pro.ProjectID
                   where pro.ProjectID == pro_id &&
                         pro.ProjectID == it.ProjectID &&
                         it.ProjectIterationID == pim.ProjectIterationID &&
                         pim.ProjectIterationMemberID == s.ProjectIterationMemberID && s.StoryCategoryID == 1 &&
                         s.StoryID == psf.StoryID &&
                         psf.AgileFactorID == af.AgileFactorID
                   group af by af.Name into tagGroup
                   select new
                   {

                       Tag = tagGroup.Key,
                       weight = (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100
                   };

public string GetTagSize(double weight)
{

    if (weight >= 99)
        return "36pt";
    else if (weight >= 80)
        return "29pt";
    else if (weight >= 64)
        return "23pt";
    else if (weight >= 48)
        return "18pt";
    else if (weight >= 32)
        return "14pt";
    else if (weight >= 10)
        return "11pt";
    else
        return "8pt";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
weight = (tagGroup.Count() == 1) ? (double)1 : (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100
```

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need, but essentially you could use the conditional operator to work around the issue.  The first param would be the smallest font, didn't know what represents it so I set it at 1.

Comment: Awesome, this was wrecking my head!

Comment: Ok, one more problem...now if the count is 2, the largest font is displayed again...I need count of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc. to fall within the appropriate % range. Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: You can keep appending tertiary ranges as in: (tagGroup.Count()  == 1) ? (double)1 : (new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5 }).Contains(tagGroup.Count()) ? (double)whateverValue : (double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100, that may get messy, but it's supported.  Check this example: http://lancefisher.net/blog/archive/2008/05/07/linq-to-sql---case-statements.aspx.  THis probably would work for ADO.NET EF too if that's what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `?:` operator:

```
weight = (tagGroup.Count() == 1) ? smallestFont : ((double)tagGroup.Count() / maxTagFrequencyNegative * 100)
```

Comment: Ok, one more problem...now if the count is 2, the largest font is displayed again...I need count of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc. to fall within the appropriate % range. Any ideas? Much appreciated!